# Troubles trying to sort a list with a specific pattern

Tags: c++

I'm on a programming exercise and I got some troubles writing a function to insert sorted in a list:
I have the following code:

```
void Node::insertNew(Object* obj) {
    list<Object*>::iterator iter = listObjects.begin();
    while (it != listObjects.end() && (*it)->getFrecuency() > obj->getFrecuency()) {
        it++;
    }
    if (it != listObjects.end() && (*it)->getFrecuency() != obj->getFrequency()) {
        while (it != listObjects.end() && (*it)->getName() < obj->getName()) {
            it++;
        }
        listObjects.insert(it, obj);
    }

}
```

I want insert sorted, in first place, by Frecuency (from highest to lowest) and in case of tie, by Name (from lowest to highest alphabetically).
But I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong.
Hope you can help me, sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having when you run this? Does it compile? Does it crash?

Comment: You could split your comparator into it's own function and use lower_bound to find the right insertion point.

Comment: Do u mean another function? How should I write it?

Comment: Just overload the operators <, <=, >, >=, == and !=, so you just don't have to worry about it later

Comment: Implementing operator< could be helpful, but with a container of pointers you need a little extra scaffolding.

Comment: Could u help me with the auxiliary function and where should I call it in the main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop says "if the frequencies are *different*, start comparing the names (while ignoring the frequencies) until you find the insertion point".

You want to find the first element whose frequency is smaller *or* has the same frequency and whose name is not less:

```
while (it != listObjects.end() 
  && ((*it)->getFrequency() > obj->getFrequency() 
     || ((*it)->getFrequency() == obj->getFrequency() 
         && (*it)->getName() < obj->getName()))) {
    it++;
}
listObjects.insert(it, obj);
```

Overloading the `<` operator makes it more convenient.

```
bool operator< (const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs)
{
    return lhs.getFrequency() > rhs.getFrequency()
        || (lhs.getFrequency() == rhs.getFrequency() && lhs.getName() < rhs.getName());
}

// ...
while (it != listObjects.end() && **it < *obj)
    it++;
listObjects.insert(it, obj);
```